# How Lazy loading of child records works in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know the above question is very common but I just wanted to know exactly when and How Hibernate is fetching the lazily loaded child records.

below is the sample table structure:

## Table Structure:

```
employee_table(e_id, e_name, e_sal)
(100, XYZ, 20000)

mobile_table(m_id, m_number, e_id)
(1, 8728271817, 100)
(2, 0983813919, 100)
```

### Employee.java

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1930751473454928876L;

    private long employeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    private double employeeSal;

    private Set<Mobile> mobiles;

    public long getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    public double getEmployeeSal() {
        return employeeSal;
    }
    public void setEmployeeSal(double employeeSal) {
        this.employeeSal = employeeSal;
    }
    public Set<Mobile> getMobiles() {
        return mobiles;
    }
    public void setMobiles(Set<Mobile> mobiles) {
        this.mobiles = mobiles;
    }
}
```

### Employee.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="edu.sandip.hibernate.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE_T">
        <id name="employeeId" column="e_id" type="long">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="employeeName" column="e_name" type="string" />
        <property name="employeeSal" column="e_sal" type="double" />

        <set name="mobiles" table="MOBILE_T" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" >
            <key>
                <column name="e_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="edu.sandip.hibernate.Mobile" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### Mobile.java

```
public class Mobile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6279006639448045512L;

    private long mobId;
    private String mobileNumber;

    private Employee employee;

    public long getMobId() {
        return mobId;
    }
    public void setMobId(long mobId) {
        this.mobId = mobId;
    }
    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }
    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((mobileNumber == null) ? 0 : mobileNumber.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Mobile other = (Mobile) obj;
        if (mobileNumber == null) {
            if (other.mobileNumber != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!mobileNumber.equals(other.mobileNumber))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Mobile.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="edu.sandip.hibernate.Mobile" table="MOBILE_T">
        <id name="mobId" column="m_id" type="long">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="mobileNumber" column="m_number" type="string" />
        <many-to-one name="employee" class="edu.sandip.hibernate.Employee" fetch="select">
            <column name="e_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Below is the code block to fetch the list of employees:

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    List<Employee> list = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Employee");
        list = query.list();
        for(Employee employee : list) {
            System.out.println("Emaployee Name: " + employee.getEmployeeName);
            Set<Mobile> mobileSet = employee.getMobiles();
            System.out.println("Mobile Numbers: ");
            for(Mobile mobile : mobileSet) {
                System.out.println(mobile.getMobileNumber());
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(session != null) {
            System.out.println("session is still alive");
            releaseSession(session);
        }
    }
    return (list);
}
```

Now, Here the Mobile numbers is the child record of Employee which is been loaded by the Hibernate lazily as per the hibernate configuration in Employee.hbm.xml (lazy = true)

In the above code, after printing the employee name I am printing the mobile numbers of that
employee by iterating the Set mobiles.

I have checked and found that the iteration of the mobileSet is actually fetching the mobileNumbers.
i.e.

```
for(Mobile mobile : mobileSet) {
    System.out.println(mobile.getMobileNumber());
}
```

SO, How It is happening? Because I am not using any hibernate specific API to fetch the lazily loaded child records. Just Iterating over the set of mobile numbers.

Then how Hibernate is fetching the child records internally? What is the background job that Hibernate is doing while I am iterating over the mobileSet?

Please help in understanding my doubt.

Comment: If you want to understand the queries it fires while you access the inner objects, mark showSql = true in the properties and debug

Answer (score 3):

In hibernate lazy loading is triggered whenever a lazy loaded property is accessed and it is still managed by the em. If you would access a lazy loaded property when the entity is detached from the entity manager you would get a org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

To apply the logic to your example:
mobile.getMobileNumber() will trigger the lazy loading in your code. Hibernate will then automaticly issue a query to the database. This works because hibernate instantiates proxy objects for lazy loaded propertys, once you try to access these proxys hibernate tries to load them in from the database. this will work if the object is managed and this will result in forementioned exception if the entity is detached. There is no need at all to use a hibernate API to trigger the lazy loading it just happens automaticly when a lazy configured property is accessed

Comment: Theoretically I understood your point. But I know that 'In hibernate lazy loading is triggered whenever a lazy loaded property is accessed'. But I wanted know HOW hibernate does this? as in the above example for fetching the Employee I am using Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Employee"); list = query.list(); But for retrieving the child records I am not explicitly using any such hibernate specific API. Then which part of my code is triggering the fetch of the lazily loaded child records i.e. set of mobileNumbers. Can you please explain.

Comment: I have edited my response to apply the explanation to your example

Answer (score 1):

In your Employee.hbm.xml file you have stated that the fetch strategy for Mobile is lazy.
That tells hibernate to generate a simple SQL statement to the table that corresponds to Employee without performing any joins with the corresponding Mobile table.
However when employee.getMobiles() is called, 
Hibernate will issue a select query to the latter table using a where clause with the primary key of the former table.

The way the fetching is implemented here leads to the infamous [N+1 problem](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-identify-and-resilve-n1)

Comment: first: If you say that 'when employee.getMobiles() is called, Hibernate will issue a select query to the latter table using a where clause with the primary key of the former table'. How Hibernate is issuing the select query as I am not using hibernate specific API call which will tell hibernate to issue one more sql query.
Second: So If I just call 'employee.getMobiles()' and don't iterate over the Set<Mobile> mobileSet and return the List<Employee> list from the above method: getAllEmployees(), Then Outside this method Will I able to retrieve the child records,mobileNumbers for each Employee?

Comment: When lazily loaded objects exist in an Entity, Hibernate uses a proxy (created with Javassist) that stands in place of the lazily loaded object. When that object is retrieved (via getMobiles() in this example) and the object is still in managed state, then the proxy triggers a new select query to the database. If the object is not managed then you get the dreaded LazyInitializationException.

I suggest that you read Java Persistence with Hibernate for the details

Answer (score 0):

This topic could help you to understand what is the trick behind lazy loading :

[How proxy loads the lazy property in Hibernate/JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937472/how-proxy-loads-the-lazy-property-in-hibernate-jpa)